# php mysqli get data showing array results but cannot echo (shows NULL)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

so my script i have done and using var_dump is showing results but when i do var_dump $row['blah']; its showing as NULL even though i can see its not when i var_dump($row) - i want to echo $customer_name for example but they show as nothing and not sure why.

Any ideas?

OUTPUT:

```
object(mysqli_result)#1 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(34) ["lengths"]=> array(34) { [0]=> int(2) [1]=> int(4) [2]=> int(23) [3]=> int(1) [4]=> int(7) [5]=> int(6) [6]=> int(7) [7]=> int(2) [8]=> int(4) [9]=> int(10) [10]=> int(10) [11]=> int(3) [12]=> int(2) [13]=> int(3) [14]=> int(2) [15]=> int(3) [16]=> int(27) [17]=> int(4) [18]=> int(2) [19]=> int(4) [20]=> int(13) [21]=> int(23) [22]=> int(15) [23]=> int(0) [24]=> int(6) [25]=> int(5) [26]=> int(8) [27]=> int(11) [28]=> int(13) [29]=> int(15) [30]=> int(0) [31]=> int(6) [32]=> int(5) [33]=> int(8) } ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) } array(28) { ["id"]=> string(2) "21" ["invoice"]=> string(4) "1000" ["product"]=> string(23) "Versa Table - Blue Jazz" ["qty"]=> string(1) "3" ["price"]=> string(7) "149.000" ["discount"]=> string(3) "134" ["subtotal"]=> string(3) "462" ["invoice_date"]=> string(10) "20/05/2015" ["invoice_due_date"]=> string(10) "13/05/2015" ["shipping"]=> string(2) "20" ["vat"]=> string(2) "92" ["total"]=> string(3) "482" ["notes"]=> string(27) "Please leave with next door" ["status"]=> string(4) "open" ["name"]=> string(13) "James Brandon" ["email"]=> string(23) "james@ambientlounge.com" ["address_1"]=> string(15) "5 Frampton Road" ["address_2"]=> string(0) "" ["town"]=> string(6) "Epping" ["county"]=> string(5) "Essex" ["postcode"]=> string(8) "CM16 6RP" ["phone"]=> string(11) "07718090809" ["name_ship"]=> string(13) "James Brandon" ["address_1_ship"]=> string(15) "5 Frampton Road" ["address_2_ship"]=> string(0) "" ["town_ship"]=> string(6) "Epping" ["county_ship"]=> string(5) "Essex" ["postcode_ship"]=> string(8) "CM16 6RP" } NULL
```

CODE:

```
include('includes/config.php');
include('header.php');
include('functions.php');

$getID = $_GET['id'];

// Connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME);

// output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('.$mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// the query
$query = "SELECT p.*, i.*, c.*
            FROM invoice_items p 
            JOIN invoices i ON i.invoice = p.invoice
            JOIN customers c ON c.invoice = i.invoice
            WHERE p.invoice = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($getID) . "'";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

var_dump($result);

// mysqli select query
if($result) {
        var_dump($row);
        $customer_name = $row['customer_name']; // customer name
        $customer_email = $row['customer_email']; // customer email
        $customer_address_1 = $row['customer_address_1']; // customer address
        $customer_address_2 = $row['customer_address_2']; // customer address
        $customer_town = $row['customer_town']; // customer town
        $customer_county = $row['customer_county']; // customer county
        $customer_postcode = $row['customer_postcode']; // customer postcode
        $customer_phone = $row['customer_phone']; // customer phone number

        //shipping
        $customer_name_ship = $row['customer_name_ship']; // customer name (shipping)
        $customer_address_1_ship = $row['customer_address_1_ship']; // customer address (shipping)
        $customer_address_2_ship = $row['customer_address_2_ship']; // customer address (shipping)
        $customer_town_ship = $row['customer_town_ship']; // customer town (shipping)
        $customer_county_ship = $row['customer_county_ship']; // customer county (shipping)
        $customer_postcode_ship = $row['customer_postcode_ship']; // customer postcode (shipping)

        // invoice details
        $invoice_number = $row['invoice_id']; // invoice number
        $invoice_date = $row['invoice_date']; // invoice date
        $invoice_due_date = $row['invoice_due_date']; // invoice due date
        $invoice_subtotal = $row['invoice_subtotal']; // invoice sub-total
        $invoice_shipping = $row['invoice_shipping']; // invoice shipping amount
        $invoice_discount = $row['invoice_discount']; // invoice discount
        $invoice_vat = $row['invoice_vat']; // invoice vat
        $invoice_total = $row['invoice_total']; // invoice total
        $invoice_notes = $row['invoice_notes']; // Invoice notes
        $invoice_status = $row['invoice_status']; // Invoice status

        var_dump($row['customer_name']);
}

?>

        <h1>Edit Invoice (<?php echo $getID; ?>)</h1>
        <hr><?php var_dump($row['customer_name']); ?>

        <div id="response" class="alert alert-success" style="display:none;">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <div class="message"></div>
        </div>

        <form method="post" id="create_invoice">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create_invoice">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <h1>
                        <img src="<?php echo COMPANY_LOGO ?>" class="img-responsive">
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 text-right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <h1>INVOICE</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <select name="invoice_status" id="invoice_status" class="form-control">
                                <option value="open" <?php if($invoice_status == "open"){?>selected<?php } ?>>Open</option>
                                <option value="paid" <?php if($invoice_status == "paid"){?>selected<?php } ?>>Paid</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding-right">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="invoice_date">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="invoice_date" placeholder="Select invoice date" data-date-format="<?php echo DATE_FORMAT ?>" value="<?php echo $invoice_date; ?>" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="invoice_due_date">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="invoice_due_date" placeholder="Select due date" data-date-format="<?php echo DATE_FORMAT ?>" value="<?php echo $invoice_due_date; ?>" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-4 float-right">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">#<?php echo INVOICE_PREFIX ?></span>
                        <input type="text" name="invoice_id" id="invoice_id" class="form-control required" placeholder="Invoice Number" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" value="<?php echo $getID; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4>Customer Information</h4>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body form-group form-group-sm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" placeholder="Enter name" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo $customer_name; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_address_1" id="customer_address_1" placeholder="Address 1" tabindex="3" value="<?php echo $customer_address_1; ?>">    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_town" id="customer_town" placeholder="Town" tabindex="5" value="<?php echo $customer_town; ?>">        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control copy-input required" name="customer_postcode" id="customer_postcode" placeholder="Postcode" tabindex="7" value="<?php echo $customer_postcode; ?>">                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="input-group float-right margin-bottom">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control copy-input required" name="customer_email" id="customer_email" placeholder="E-mail address" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" tabindex="2" value="<?php echo $customer_email; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input" name="customer_address_2" id="customer_address_2" placeholder="Address 2" tabindex="4" value="<?php echo $customer_address_2; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_county" id="customer_county" placeholder="County" tabindex="6" value="<?php echo $customer_county; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="customer_phone" id="invoice_phone" placeholder="Phone number" tabindex="8" value="<?php echo $customer_phone; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4>Shipping Information</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body form-group form-group-sm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom required" name="customer_name_ship" id="customer_name_ship" placeholder="Enter name" tabindex="9" value="<?php echo $customer_name_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom" name="customer_address_2_ship" id="customer_address_2_ship" placeholder="Address 2" tabindex="11" value="<?php echo $customer_address_2_ship; ?>">    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="customer_county_ship" id="customer_county_ship" placeholder="County" tabindex="13" value="<?php echo $customer_county_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom required" name="customer_address_1_ship" id="customer_address_1_ship" placeholder="Address 1" tabindex="10" value="<?php echo $customer_address_1_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom required" name="customer_town_ship" id="customer_town_ship" placeholder="Town" tabindex="12" value="<?php echo $customer_town_ship; ?>">                           
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="customer_postcode_ship" id="customer_postcode_ship" placeholder="Postcode" tabindex="14" value="<?php echo $customer_postcode_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / end client details section -->
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="invoice_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="500">
                            <h4><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs add-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> Item</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Qty</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Price</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th width="300">
                            <h4>Discount</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Sub Total</h4>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        foreach($invoice_product as $key => $value) {
                            $item_product = $value;
                            // $item_description = $_POST['invoice_product_desc'][$key];
                            $item_qty = $row['invoice_product_qty'][$key];
                            $item_price = $row['invoice_product_price'][$key];
                            $item_discount = $row['invoice_product_discount'][$key];
                            $item_subtotal = $row['invoice_product_sub'][$key];
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm  no-margin-bottom">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-group-sm item-input invoice_product" name="invoice_product[]" placeholder="Enter item title and / or description" value="<?php echo $item_product; ?>">
                                <p class="item-select">or <a href="#">select an item</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm no-margin-bottom">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate" name="invoice_product_qty[]" value="1" value="<?php echo $item_qty; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm  no-margin-bottom">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate invoice_product_price required" name="invoice_product_price[]" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="0.00" value="<?php echo $item_price; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm  no-margin-bottom">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate" name="invoice_product_discount[]" placeholder="Enter % or value (ex: 10% or 10.50)" value="<?php echo $item_discount; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate-sub" name="invoice_product_sub[]" id="invoice_product_sub" value="0.00" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" value="<?php echo $item_subtotal; ?>" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div id="invoice_totals" class="padding-right row text-right">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group-sm textarea no-margin-bottom">
                        <textarea class-"form-control" name="invoice_notes" placeholder="Please enter any order notes here." value="<?php echo $invoice_notes; ?>"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding-right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>Sub Total:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-sub-total"> <?php echo $invoice_subtotal; ?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_subtotal" id="invoice_subtotal" value="<?php echo $invoice_subtotal; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>Discount:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-discount"> <?php echo $invoice_discount; ?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_discount" id="invoice_discount" value="<?php echo $invoice_discount; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong class="shipping">Shipping:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate shipping" name="invoice_shipping" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="0.00" value="<?php echo $invoice_shipping; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if (ENABLE_VAT == true) { ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>TAX/VAT:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-vat" data-enable-vat="<?php echo ENABLE_VAT ?>" data-vat-rate="<?php echo VAT_RATE ?>" data-vat-method="<?php echo VAT_INCLUDED ?>">0.00</span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_vat" id="invoice_vat">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>Total:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-total"> <?php echo $invoice_total; ?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_total" id="invoice_total" value="<?php echo $invoice_total; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 margin-top btn-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="action_edit_invoice" class="btn btn-success float-right" value="Update Invoice" data-loading-text="Updating...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="insert" class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Select an item</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <?php popProductsList(); ?>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="selected">Add</button>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

<?php
    include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: add output of var_dump($row)

Comment: ive worked it out dont worry :)

Comment: ACtually can you help me with my foreach to loop products as thats not working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you assign data to $row it means $result is nothing;

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

var_dump($result);

// mysqli select query
if($result) {
```

you code would be

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $customer_name = $row['customer_name'];
.......
}
```